# Loading Multiple Images into a Scrolled Composite in SWT

Tags: java, image, swt

My project requirement is such that I need to load multiple images (to be specific `*.tif` files) into a scrolled composite using Java SWT. Accordingly, I am only able to load a single image file into the scrolled composite. But I'm not able to figure out the code for loading multiple images from a particular directory, which contains those image files.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to create a 'container' of `Label` or `Composite` to which you set selected images. The container will then wrap with `ScrolledComposite` and you're done.

See [ScrolledComposite with wrapping content](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet166.java) snippet.

Result then looks like this

[image]